# dimissViewControllerAnimated completion: nil?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, deprecated

I'm trying to update my app for iOS 6 and above. I'm removing the code that has been deprecated, namely dimissModalViewControllerAnimated. How come Xcode does not recognize dimissViewControllerAnimated as a method unless I put a "completion: nil" after it like this:

```
[self dimissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion nil];
```

What does that last part even mean? When I put nil, is that opposed to putting something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the API was changed to this call. The last argument takes a completion block which is executed after the dismiss animation finsihed.

When you pass nil it will execute nothing because nothing is there.

Comment: So to replace [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES], [self dimissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion nil] will do?

Answer (score 0):

[complete:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated%3acompletion%3a) is a block of code that gets executed after the modal view controller is dismissed. The block you pass in is optional and it is safe to pass it nil if you have no completion behavior.

If you pass in nil, it basically the same as the deprecated [dismissModalViewController:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated%3a)

Comment: Sorry, side question, what do I replace something like "navigationController.modalViewController" with? ".modalViewController" is also deprecated, I tried ".viewController" but that didn't work.

Comment: In the future, please refrain from asking unrelated questions in comments. Use presentedViewController. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentedViewController